# AWS EMR Resource Manager REST APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-emr, resourcemanager

For Apache Hadoop installation, there are REST APIs available to get the status of an application or to know a list of running applications etc. Those are mentioned at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API

Is there any documentation for the same for EMR REST APIs? I am not able to find. When I execute same APIs as plain hadoop on EMR, I can see a difference. e.g. queue name has to passed in as root.queuename in apache hadoop and in case of EMR root word is not required in the queuename. If someone can point me to the documentation of similar REST APIs for EMR, that will be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later understood that Capacity scheduler does not add word root in identifying the queue. I was using capacity scheduler in my EMR cluster and Fair scheduler in local setup and that is why the difference of word root in identifying the queue.

This had nothing to do with EMR.